# How can Python know the signatures of a dll function

Tags: python, c, windows, dll

I am developing a programming language, and I want it to be able to access dll (or shared libs). I know that python has a `CDLL` function to do this. In C, I know that to call a dll function, you must load the library using `LoadLibrary`, and get the procedure using `GetProcAddress`, and finally cast it into a function.

```
typedef void (__stdcall *testf)();

HINSTANCE lib = LoadLibrary("test.dll");
testf proc = (testf) GetProcAddress(lib, "testf");
proc();
```

But in python, the third step is not done.

```
from ctypes import *

lib = CDLL("test.dll")
lib.testf() #not casting the function anywhere
```

How is this done, and how can I achieve the same thing in C?

Comment: It seems likely that Python is doing that step in the background, I don't see how you could get around needing to find the address of a function that's loaded in memory.

Comment: It doesn't know, it uses duck-typing. Try passing wrong arguments and see what happens. All answers to your questions can be obtained by reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

Comment: Does python perform this task on it's own, or is there some underlying C code. I was under the impression that C was acting in the background, and if it is, shouldn't the C code require the casting?

Comment: Not sure about the concrete implementation, hopefully someone can give you a thorough answer. But, the casting is really only cosmetic, it give the pointer a type, so `foo()` is syntactically correct. Nothing stops you from casting to a wrong signature, so C impl of  `ctypes` can just cast to the signature you called the function with and capture any exception that might arise from calling the function wrongly. See section "Foreign functions" in the link. Or it can leverage the fact that `int(*)()` is a function accepting any arguments and do the same.

Comment: The latter is more probable, it also goes with the statement that by default the library expects the functions return an `int`. The casts would have to hard-wired somewhere since C does not have templates. `void*(*)()` is the most general I guess.

Comment: BTW: You're asking how an open source program performs a certain task. You can go and read the sourcecode!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctypes` is guessing. Python is dynamic - `lib.testf()` causes python to call the `lib` object's `__getattriute__` / `__getattr__` methods. That method is implemented by `ctypes` to get the function's entry point using its python name. It then provides a proxy to your python code to marshal parameters for the call. This proxy has default rules for what the parameters are actually going to be. When you call the function, this proxy gets whatever parameters you happened to pass in and once again guesses about how those should be translated to C. If the defaults aren't correct, the proxy can be configured with a schema to translate between python and C. This is covered in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

Note: Things can go terribly wrong quickly with `ctypes`.

`ctypes` has both python level and C level code. You can browse the cpython source at https://github.com/python/cpython. Look for `Lib/ctypes` and `Modules/_ctypes`.

Comment: [cffi](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) is much simpler in this regard, since it parses C declarations in headers.

Comment: @ErykSun - That's a good point. Since OP is developing a programming language, [SWIG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG) may be a good option.

Comment: I assumed using CFFI in ABI mode. But there are several popular frameworks if you're building an extension module to wrap a library, including CFFI in API mode and [Cython](https://cython.org).

Answer (score 1):

`ctypes` doesnot really know anything. `ctypes` assumes that *every symbol* is a *function* (even if it was a variable), that uses *default argument promotions*, and *returns an `int`* I.e. it is really a miracle if it does work correctly with anything at all.